# Which character from Mahabharata is the one who have this history?

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request

I was remembering a character from the Epic, he was a sage(who was a Rishi) who didn't want to do marriage (he didn't have any interest in Woman) but then, at last, his father or some other relative of him send three beautiful ladies and he was finally attracted to one of them due to her dance and finally married her. If I am correct with this history of his, who is this character?

Comment: I am sorry if the question is wrongly framed or anything . If anything wrong tell me please , if needed i can ask another problem which can help me more easily

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I remember just this detail of that Rishi @Community Bot , and i just need the name of that Rishi